# System hangs on calling a wx frame from wx frame

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, multiprocessing, wxpython

I am creating an wx app which draw rectangles on mouse movement with a side panel that allows user to start and stop drawing rectangle. But on running the following code SidePanel hangs and shows not responding.
I tried both multiprocessing and multi threading but problem still exists.

```
class SidePanel(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="Anchor Creation")
        self.SetWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
        panel = wx.Panel(self, size=(100,100))
        self.Show()


class Desktop(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None, title='Hello World')

        self.t = SidePanel()

        self.AssociateHandle(win32gui.GetDesktopWindow())

        self.old = [0,0,0,0]
        self.overlay = wx.Overlay()       
        self.cnt = 0
        self.gen = Gen()
        self.mouse_listener()

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    mf = Desktop()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: What does this self.mouse_listener do?

Comment: It calls up a mouse listener that tracks the movements of the mouse and then draws the rectangle. `self.AssociateHandle(win32gui.GetDesktopWindow())` Doesn't allows  me to create an other frame but it allows me to draw directly on the screen so I can't remove it as well.

Comment: If you add print("before") before self.mouse_listener() and print("after") after self.mouse_listener(), will you see after on the console?

Comment: Yes I am receiving both

Comment: Have you tried multithreading (the right way)? ¿Using CallAfter etc? If not, now you know why it doesn't work. See: https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/